# Forum or list for WWDC attendees?

Tags: discussion, wwdc

I guess I haven't found the right search terms to find this on my own, so I figured I ask.

Is there a forum or something out there where people who are going to WWDC trade information? Stuff like trip advice, informal birds-of-a-feather sessions, parties, etc. Or does all that kind of coordination happen over Twitter these days?

Comment: I've moved this to meta since it's more of a discussion and a list. The main site is very much not a place for lists (we're not trying to be wikipedia) and also it's of marginal interest to the great majority of Apple Users as opposed to Apple Developers. Let's see how this works on meta.

Comment: @bmike : Since all WWDC attendees (other than keynote press) have to be registered in Apple's Developer program, this question may be more appropriate for the programmers.stackexchange site.

Answer (score 2):

I'd be happy to open a chat room for people to discuss WWDC and share links and stories. If it gets too crowded, we can make others. Would that suit your desires to have a conversation and share WWDC plans?

Answer (score 1):

All WWDC attendees should have access to Apple's Developer Forums.  Some discussion seems to take place there.

Comment: Yes - and you can bet there will be lots of chat here on anything mac or iOS that gets announced at the usual opening keynote.